# I have a DB trigger that is triggered after insert on a table.

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

Would the time taken for calling insert query from java code be sum of time taken by INSERT query and the trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. The trigger code essentially becomes a part of the triggering statement (in your case `INSERT`) execution plan.